# Splitting an iOS audio recording into multiple files

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I'm recording audio using AVFoundation in LPCM, then splitting it into multiple chunks based on time.

I've come across a few different ways of doing the splitting:

1. Treat the recording as an `AVAsset` and then use
   `AVAssetExportSession`, or several (see below).
2. Just chunk the raw binary of the recording based on the number of
       samples, like in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885443/ios-record-audio-and-split-it-into-files-in-real-time).

`AVAssetExportSession` feels a bit video-oriented, and the way I see it, I need to create a separate export session for each chunk. I'm concerned about this, and frankly it takes me deep into callback hell.

What I currently have is something like this pseudo-code:

```
currentAsset!.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["exportable"]) {
    if status is ok {
        export()
    }
}

func export() {
    for chunk in chunks {
        exportChunk(chunkTime)
    }
}

func exportChunk() {
    if let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: currentAsset!, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough) {
        // set exporter parameters
        exporter.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            // check status, update progress etc.
        }
    }
}
```

Doing the chunking based on the samples would seem like a straightforward thing to do. I think I could easily divide it into a GCD serial queue.

Are there any concerns? Is there something I'm missing? How would you approach this?

Comment: Can you explain how you’re recording? With a capture session, AVAudioRecorder or AVAudioEngine?

Comment: I'm recording the mixer output from AVAudioEngine into an AVAudioFile. The file is created OK, so the recording is not the problem. Basically I'm just trying to find out if multiple AVAssetExportSessions in a tight loop would be a problem.

Comment: So this is a post processing step to performed after the recording has finished? If you're careful with your timestamps (use the file sample rate as timebase) it should be fine. If you're creating chunks as you're recording, or if you don't want the intermediate file or unintentional transcoding, then go with that other answer.

Comment: It is a post processing step. The CMTime timestamps seem to work OK for my purposes at least. I didn't want to chunk during recording, can't remember why, but why not. Thanks for your insight.